# How do I write a recursive algorithm for permutations?

Tags: java, recursion, permutation, pseudocode

my question concerns a recursive way to output permutations given an input of integers.
Each of the integers represents a set of letters like a phone's keypad.

So the sets would look like:

```
1: {}
2: {"A", "B", "C"}
3: {"D", "E", "F"}
4: {"G", "H", "I"}
etc...
```

I need to produce code that given a series of numbers would output all permutations of the letters.

So, an input of 123 would output:
AD, AE, AF, BD, BF, CD, CE, CF

Psuedo-code would be preferred, and I'm only somewhat fluent in Java, but any help would be welcome.

Please feel free to give feedback on how this question was asked, I'm still not sure how to post here properly yet.

Comment: Why recursive?  wouldn't iterative be easier?

Comment: @jsobo The algorithm is required to be recursive, I can do an iterative one without too much trouble, but recursion is still a huge stretch for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a non recursive function that takes two `Set` and returns a `Set` of permutation:

```
private Set<String> getPermutations(Set<String> a, Set<String> b){
...
}
```

Then you can have a recursive function

```
public Set<String> recursivePermutations(List<Set<String>> sets){
    if(sets.size() ==2){
        return getPermutations(sets.get(0), sets.get(1));
    }else{
        return getPermutations(sets.get(0),recursivePermutations(sets.sublist(1,sets.size()-1));
    }
}
```

you might want to add a safe guards for when you have only 1 elements in your List and also use `Collection` if you don't really need a list.

**EDIT**

The main idea behind recursion is to have two cases: a simple case (when you have only two sets) when you can apply a non-recursive method, and a recursive case when you have to apply the function again on a problem of reduced size.

In my example, if you have more than 2 sets, you recursively reapply the same function but with a smaller number of set (the function is applied on the first element and on the rest of the sets).

Imagine you first apply your function on a list of `n` sets. The second time you apply your function you will have a list of `n-1` and so on until you reach the case when `n=2`. In this case you don't need to use recursion because it's a trivial case.

Comment: I can also details the `getPermutations` method if it's a problem

Comment: I don't really understand what is going on in your recursive function. Please excuse my ignorance...

Comment: @SamSam Ok let me improve my answer

Comment: I can understand what you've done, thanks.
This method needs a list though, what kind of list is this?
Linked?
The compiler complains about `List` not being a generic, but then goes back and demands a generic type. I assume this means I need a list that holds generic elements?

Comment: @SamSam Yes in Java `List` is an interface. One of the most common realisation of this interface are `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`. For this particular example you can go for any of them. So you can do something like `List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>()`

Comment: I would, but my reputation isn't high enough

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it in `F#`:

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

let pad = new Dictionary<int, string>()
pad.Add(2, "A,B,C")
pad.Add(3, "D,E,F")
pad.Add(4, "G,H,I")

let permutations = new List<string>()

let rec permute(digits: int list, alphas: string list) =    
    if List.length digits > 0 && List.length alphas = 0 then
        permute(digits, ["#"] |> List.append (pad.[digits.[0]].Split([|','|]) |> List.ofArray))
    else
        match alphas with
        | [_] ->
            match digits with
            | h::t -> permute(t, [])
            | _ -> ()
        | h::t ->
            for i = 0 to List.length alphas - 2 do
                permutations.Add(h + alphas.[i])
            for j = 1 to List.length digits - 1 do
                let others = pad.[digits.[j]].Split([|','|])
                for o in others do
                    permutations.Add(h + o)
            permute(digits, t)
        | _ -> ()

permute([2;3;4;], [])

seq { 
    for o in permutations do 
        yield o
        yield o.[1].ToString() + o.[0].ToString()
}
|> Seq.distinct
|> Seq.sort 
|> Seq.iter(fun s -> Console.WriteLine(s))
;;
```

**Output**

```
[2; 3; 4]
[]


[2; 3; 4]
[A; B; C; ... ]

AA
AB
AC
AD
AE
AF
AG
AH
AI

[2; 3; 4]
[B; C; #]

BB
BC
BD
BE
BF
BG
BH
BI

[2; 3; 4]
[C; #]

CC
CD
CE
CF
CG
CH
CI

[2; 3; 4]
[#]


[3; 4]
[]


[3; 4]
[D; E; F; ... ]

DD
DE
DF
DG
DH
DI

[3; 4]
[E; F; #]

EE
EF
EG
EH
EI

[3; 4]
[F; #]

FF
FG
FH
FI

[3; 4]
[#]


[4]
[]


[4]
[G; H; I; ... ]

GG
GH
GI

[4]
[H; I; #]

HH
HI

[4]
[I; #]

II

[4]
[#]


[]
[]

AA
AB
AC
AD
AE
AF
AG
AH
AI
BA
BB
BC
BD
BE
BF
BG
BH
BI
CA
CB
CC
CD
CE
CF
CG
CH
CI
DA
DB
DC
DD
DE
DF
DG
DH
DI
EA
EB
EC
ED
EE
EF
EG
EH
EI
FA
FB
FC
FD
FE
FF
FG
FH
FI
GA
GB
GC
GD
GE
GF
GG
GH
GI
HA
HB
HC
HD
HE
HF
HG
HH
HI
IA
IB
IC
ID
IE
IF
IG
IH
II
```